# Django Custom Password Reset Form widget not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

Stumped as to why my template isn't showing my custom password reset form.

Here is code:

forms.py

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

email = forms.EmailField(
    label='', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'placetest@test.com',
        'class': 'form-field', }))
```

Views.py

```
class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
form_class = CustomPasswordResetForm
template_name = 'password_reset.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('password_reset', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('login_success/', login_success, name='login_success'),]
```

Template

```
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="form-container" id="pwrest">
    <div class="form-title">
        <h2>Enter your email address</h2>
    </div>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>email</p>
        <div>{{ form.email }}</div>
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send me instructions!">
    </form>

</div>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
.form-field{
    width: 300px;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}
```

Rendered HTML

```
    <div class="form-title">
        <h2>Enter your email address</h2>
    </div>

    <form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="TOKEN">
        <p>email</p>
        <div><input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" maxlength="254" required id="id_email"></div>
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send me instructions!">
    </form>

</div>

</div>
```

When I view the template in my browser, I am seeing the form field as the default, its almost like its just not recognizing the CSS class.

I'm not sure what I've missed.

.

Comment: How is your CSS being included in your page/template?

Comment: Im using the load tag to load static files, my css is in my static folder. fwiw I am using the same form-field class on my login form and its working.

Comment: Can you inspect the rendered HTML (page source) and share what the rendered email field looks like? Does it include the class and attrs it should?

Comment: Added that to original post, it does not include the correct class